# Separating AST creation and computation with boost spirit

Tags: c++, boost, syntax, tree, calculator

I try to build a very simple calculator supporting x,y,+,-,*,/(,). The idea is simple:

1. Build syntax tree from input string (which may be: "x+3y")
2. For given x,y calculate the result by parsing the syntax tree, and inserting ints for x and y.

With boost 1.46, you can easily do both steps at once, using parse_phrase(). However, I have to execute step 2 a million of times, while the parsing does not change. So I'd like to separate this (like it was usual in the classic spirit versions). How can I do this? (Please note: boost 1.46 has no utree data structure yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution meanwhile. It is pretty simple, look at [the boost docs linked here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/example/qi/calc2_ast.cpp).

The main() function contains this code:

```
expression_ast ast;
ast_print printer;
bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, calc, space, ast);

if (r && iter == end)
{
    // [...]
    printer(ast);
    // [...]
}
```

There are actually multiple phrase_parse() functions in boost. There are variations of the phrase_parse without and "variation[s] of the phrase_parse with an additional argument: the parser's attribute.", as stated [in the boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/number_list_attribute___one_more__with_style.html). In the above code, `ast` is the parser's attribute; `printer` then evaluates the ast.

If we wanted to evaluate the printer with different values from outside, we would pass them to printer before each call of `printer(ast)`.

Note for 1.46: There's no `boost::utree` in yet. However, the AST in this example is a replacement with full functionaliy.